# While deploying mule 3 application on tomcat, getting this following error. Couldn't understand/find why I'm getting this error

Tags: tomcat, deployment, mule

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.mule.config.pool.ThreadPoolFactory: Provider org.mule.config.pool.DefaultThreadPoolFactory not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.mule.config.PreferredObjectSelector.select(PreferredObjectSelector.java:54)
    at org.mule.config.pool.ThreadPoolFactory.newInstance(ThreadPoolFactory.java:50)
    at org.mule.config.ImmutableThreadingProfile.<init>(ImmutableThreadingProfile.java:33)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextBuilder.createMuleWorkManager(DefaultMuleContextBuilder.java:278)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextBuilder.createWorkManager(DefaultMuleContextBuilder.java:271)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextBuilder.getWorkManager(DefaultMuleContextBuilder.java:206)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextBuilder.buildMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextBuilder.java:105)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.buildMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:248)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:211)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:103)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.createMuleContext(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:165)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:94)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.contextInitialized(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5653)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1007)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried using servlet and tomcat connectors, but getting the same error. Please help/guide me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: Also please share flow and configurations (in XML as text) to understand what is the application doing.

Comment: @aled edited the question by adding error and xml file. Please look into this issue

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a classloading issue, probably related to a misplaced JAR library. Ensure you have followed the steps from the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/deploying-mule-as-a-service-to-tomcat) to deploy a Mule application to Tomcat. Also check the version, to see if the version of [Tomcat is supported for Mule](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/application-server-based-hot-deployment), and if the application is using any provided library that should be provided instead of packaged, as the documentation indicates.

Comment: I added the available version for few libraries not the version mentioned in document(for these libraries log4j-core,log4j-jcl,log4j-slf4j-impl,wrapper). Will that cause the issue? And I had a doubt, can we for sure deploy any mule 3 application in tomcat/jetty that uses different connectors?

Comment: if you added the version provided in the Mule distribution that should be Ok. Don't use a newer version from the Internet. It is possible however that those libraries can conflict with Tomcat libraries. Connectors libraries should be packaged with the application. Are you building the application with Maven?

Comment: Yes, I added version provided in mule distribution. And yes, I'm building the application with maven. How to package connector libraries with mule application, I'm building the war file by adding web.xml and running maven command "mvn package", is this correct?

Comment: You have to add the dependencies for the connectors. Also Maven may not know how to package correctly a Mule application sometimes when packaging it as a war.

Comment: Ok, just a clarification that, it is possible to deploy mule 3 applications to tomcat/jetty but not mule 4, right? And do we have anything like servlet outbound in flow.xml file?

Comment: Mule 4 doesn't support Tomcat or any embedded deployment. There is no servlet outbound Endpoint. Check the documentation.